# How can I debug Skia from chromium in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, chromium

I trying to debug chromium (ver. 72.0.3626.122) on Mac most specifically I trying to trigger breakpoints in third_party\Skia. I try to follow official documentation https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-os-x but without luck. I prefer to debug in xcode but if you know any better approach how to debug skia please help me. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but if it's because skia is disabled, you can try to force it to be enabled (it might not be possible on macOs). You can check if it is disabled at `chrome://gpu`. If skia is enabled and breakpoints still don't work let me know